# $A^o$ , is unit in mathematical?

Tags: calculus

What is $A^o$ represent ? what unit is it ?(in mathematical i mean )

[image]

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angstrom

Comment: Note that $A$ to the power of $o$ would be $A^o$, so it's not an adequate description of what you're trying to describe.

Comment: Isn't this off-topic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it denotes ANGSTROMS. 10 Angstroms equals 1 Nanometer.

Comment: according to @Carsten Schultz the Angstrom  is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angstrom

Answer (score 0):

$A^o$ is for "ANGSTROM" as $1A^o=10^{-8}$cm

Comment: according to @Carsten Schultz the Angstrom  is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angstrom

Comment: yes I just put the unit only in cm but @user3234456 put that clearly